# How to get the PHP value `max_upload_size` from a .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have configured some PHP settings in my  .htaccess file.

However now I need to retrieve that information.

I tried this script:

```
$max_upload = min((int)ini_get('post_max_size'), (int)ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
$max_upload = $max_upload * 1024;
```

But that gets the information from the php.ini file and that value is different than what is configured.

Is there any way to get any information out a .htaccess file?

My .htaccess file has this:

```
# Do not remove this line or mod_rewrite rules and search engine friendly URLs will stop working
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(videos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

#Edit values below

php_value post_max_size 5000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 5000M
php_value max_execution_time 600
LimitRequestBody 5368709120
```

Comment: Are you using PHP CLI or web?

Comment: I am using the web version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getenv()` function:

```
<?php
   echo getenv('post_max_size')
?>
```

Comment: That doesn't work, please see the edited question for my .htaccess configuration.

Comment: If it doesn't work, then you are probably not running PHP as a module or you have `AllowOverride` directive off, and the given htaccess doesn't take any effect

Comment: I am using XAMPP on Windows.

Comment: So are you sure that the htaccess directive works?

Comment: I am rewriting things in `.htaccess` so I think it does, I edited the OP with my full `.htaccess`.